# Swift UnsafePointer<T>(data.bytes).memory crash under some (but not all) circumstances

Tags: swift, struct, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I have the following struct:

```
struct Identity {
    var id: Int
    var createdAt: NSDate
    var string: String
    var apnsToken: String
}
```

Over the course of my application's execution, instances (?) of this struct are turned into `NSData` (using the following code) and stored in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
var id = Identity(id: 0, createdAt: NSDate(), string: "string", apnsToken: "<apns-token-here>")
var data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &id, length: sizeof(Identity),freeWhenDone:false)
```

When I try to get a struct from the `NSData` instance, it crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (it's a code 1):

```
var id = UnsafePointer<Identity>(userDefaultsData.bytes).memory
```

However, this only happens when I get the `NSData` instance from NSUserDefaults. If I do something like below, it works without a crash.

```
var id = Identity(id: 0, createdAt: NSDate(), string: "string", apnsToken: "<apns-token-here>")
var data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &id, length: sizeof(Identity),freeWhenDone:false)
var idPrime = UnsafePointer<Identity>(data.bytes).memory
```

The assembly code dumped by the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is somewhere halfway through objc_retain, after an `and` instruction.

UPDATE:

I wasn't completely honest. The data is retrieved from the keychain in ObjC, bridge_transfer cast to an `NSData` from a CF data object. The CF object comes from `SecItemCopy()` as an out param. I thought `NSUserDefaults` would be more relatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because this line:

```
var data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: &id, length: sizeof(Identity),freeWhenDone:false)
```

will *not* render the `String`s (or any other type that allocates its own memory, like an array) into byte form.  Instead all it will do is serialize the *pointer* to the string’s memory into the `NSData` bytes.

This obviously is going to lead to explosions if the memory is no longer there.  Which is why it might seem to be working when you do it all in one go, but not when you store to user defaults and then, later or maybe even in a different process, get it back out.

Instead, you’ll need to do something like store the strings into their own `NSData` objects (say with `NSData(base64EncodedString:options:)`) and then store that too.

Comment: see my update above, not that it matters. Your answer makes a ton of sense!